# Laravel 5 stop login after register

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, frameworks

I'm using Laravel 5 standard scaffolding for the auth system, and am trying to override the default behaviour of auto-logging in the user straight after registration.

I have found a few answers on here but none work. I have tried overriding the register method in the AuthController to stop the login from happening:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
        $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

At the moment, this is registering the user and still logging them in after. Has anyone got any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was missing the user variable, I added the method like this and it worked:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```